# Returning PayPal Transaction ID

Tags: php, paypal

I am developing a Paypal form on my website, but am having a problem retrieving the Transaction Id. The way that I have done it before doesn't seem to work anymore.

In my form I have a php return page that gets the Transaction Id via the following script:

```
$transaction_id = $_REQUEST['txn_id'];
```

But it returns empty.

I see in the forums that I must set the Auto Return Function to `on` in my PayPal Account. The problem is that I have various return forms depending on the type of upgrade they choose, or the specific website. If I turn this to `on` with one URL, all my sites will return to the wrong page.

Could anyone please advise me how to do this?

Comment: Need more infot to be able to help for that

Answer (score 0):

For most PayPal APIs you can specify either a return URL or a success and failure URLs to which PayPal will return the user after completing or canceling the payment.  The URL set in the configuration is used only if no redirect URL is providing in the call.